# Keeping scrollbar in same position live chart

Tags: amcharts

When creating a live chart in AmCharts (example: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/ATQUm/)
it seems that when one triggers `this.state.chart.validateData()` the scope of the scrollbar is being reset to the full-scope unless the user clicks and holds down the scrollbar in the same position.

Is there any way to keep that scope as the data is being updated, without holding the button down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the date selection to persist between updates, you can set [`zoomOutOnDataUpdate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomOutOnDataUpdate) to false in the chart object and the scrollbar will stay on the selected date range; for example, if you're zoomed on 2017-07-01 through 2017-08-01, that date range will still be in view between updates.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ATQUm/2066/)

If you're sliding old points off the chart like in that demo, then `zoomOutOnDataUpdate` doesn't quite work out, UI-wise, since the date range  will eventually fall off as the points are removed, as you'll likely notice in the above demo (the right scrollbar handle is slowly moving left). In this instance, you'll want to maintain the chart's current [`startIndex`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#startIndex) and [`endIndex`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#endIndex) and call [`zoomToIndexes`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomToIndexes) after you update, i.e.

```
    var startIndex = chart.startIndex;
    var endIndex = chart.endIndex;
    chart.validateData();
    chart.zoomToIndexes(startIndex, endIndex);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ATQUm/2067/)

FYI, the fiddle you linked uses an older version of AmCharts (v2). My fiddles are using the latest v3 release.

Comment: In amCharts 4, you can use `Axis.keepSelection` flag. [Reference](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/pre-zooming-an-axis/#Relative_pre_zooming)